# Specify string pattern in hasNext(String pattern)

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I was wondering if you could specify what to scan for in hasNext(string pattern). For example, I want to retrieve the first three characters of the line being scanned. So is there a way to specify something such as

```
     scanner.hasNext("//c//c//c");
```

where I want to grab the first 3 alphabetic characters of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanner.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z]{3}");
```

[Working test here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B3%7D&input=Next%20line%20of%20data.).